# How to change font (size/family) in PyScripter?

Tags: python, windows, fonts, python-2.7, pyscripter

I just started taking an online course for computer science learning Python. I use PyScripter, and at the site, the examples are in "Source Code Pro". I really like that font, and have already downloaded it and use it in Notepad++, but I would also like to know how to use it in PyScripter, but I cannot find anywhere in the editing panels or context menus that allow for font changing. (Additionally, the text is too small).

I don't know if Stack Overflow is a great place for this as I think SO is meant for actual programmatic problems, but I've googled everywhere and this is my last resort.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** I am using PyScripter for Python 2.7 (for now) on Windows XP Professional. I would also like to *not* have to use skin editors, as I only want to change the font family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration for this answer: Pyscripter 2.4.3.0 (latest at this time) on Windows XP SP3 with numerous fonts already installed and available in Pyscripter.  Python26 and Python27 installed.

**Note:** The helpfile says "Pyscripter requires the use of monospace or non-proportional fonts."

Procedure:

1. Searched for and downloaded Source Code Pro (v1.017)
2. Installed it per instructions
3. Pyscripter Tools menu > Options > Editor Options
4. Display tab > click Font
5. Select "Source Code Pro" from list of fonts
6. Select Style and Size if desired
7. Press OK to accept Font options
8. Press OK to accept Edition options and apply settings to current environment
9. Source Code Pro is now the default font

Setting the font family, style and size in Pyscripter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhppd.png
(WTH, Apparently I am too lame to be trusted with embedding images or any hyperlinks... O_o)