# About font of python interpreter in PyScripter

Tags: python-3.x, pyscripter

I am using PyScripter as IDE for Python.
`Python version 3.3.2` 64 bit version.
Python interpreter in scripter is very small for visualisation.

Can anybody please help me how to increase the font of python interpreter in PyScripter?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737793/how-to-change-font-size-family-in-pyscripter

Answer (score 4):

In PyScripter 2.5.3 right mouse click on interpreter window and to choose in a pop-up menu 'interpreter editor option'.